# Laravel 5.3 and Sentinel replacing artisan make:auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm trying to use the scaffolding created by the `artisan make:auth` command for laravel 5.3, but to replace the functions there with Sentinel. In the create method of the RegisterController, I'm making the call to sentinel like so:

```
return Sentinel::register([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => $data['password'],

        ]);
```

But I'm getting an error when trying to run this.

```
    FatalThrowableError in SessionGuard.php line 441:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an 
instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of 
Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser given, 
called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/*****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 35
```

I'm guessing this is because the Sentinel::register method doesn't return an instance of this user. How would I go about getting an instance of the Sentinel user back from the creation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice would be never mess these two up, if you want use sentinel, let it fly solo then, can not see any point to mix these two together.